# How do I disable tab stacking in Opera 11.01

Tags: gui, opera

There's new feature in Opera 11.01 called [tab stacking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hqSGGk1YTI). It helps you to hoard tabs.

It works for (and annoys) me in Opera (11.01 build 1190) under Win32, but somehow doesn't appear in the same build for Linux.

Does anybody know how to disable tab stacking?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this too. Maybe someone found a way since 2011 ? :D

Comment: @Alex: How does this feature affect you negatively? From what I can tell, the use of the feature seems to be completely optional. Unless you *accidentally* drag tabs onto each other I guess.

Comment: yes, that's the problem. you can easily drag the mouse accidentally on the tabs and you get them stacked :|

Comment: @Alex: OK; after looking around for 20 minutes, I'm sure there is still no (built-in) way to do it. And Opera's developer portal is too slow for me to look up if it can be done through extensions. Sorry :(

Comment: @Alex Yes as I have make a deep search on it and check the opera community too but there is no way yet.

Comment: [Opera's stance on Tab Stacking](https://twitter.com/opera/status/42965837606420481)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing that I've found is this **patch by DitherSky**:

http://my.opera.com/DitherSky/blog/disable-tab-stacking

http://pastebin.com/LkV60SMK

You can try it with [different opera builds](ftp://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/win/). Tab stacking removal **works** for me in Opera 11.62 win32.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that there is not a way to disable tab stacking, although the developers would probably give the option in a future release.

Comment: It's been nearly two years since Opera introduced Tab Stacking. (It was introduced in Opera 11 - released Dec. 16, 2010.) Currently, there is still no option (or an extension) that will disable it. [Opera's stance on Tab Stacking remains the same](https://twitter.com/opera/status/42965837606420481).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there's no way. For future reference, try the preference editor (about:config). It has just about every setting you can change.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can't disable it,

Tab stacking only works when dragging a tab onto an other, and when you drag a little further it switches places, just like in older builds.
Tab stacking is nice function, but sometimes it's really annoying.

`I think the best options would be to make tab stacking available while holding some modification key - e.g. Ctrl + drag'n'drop.`

Comment: urwell, no problem

Comment: How to "make tab stacking available while holding some modification key - e.g. Ctrl + drag'n'drop"?  Where can I set this option?